# Source of LXDE panel menu available application categories and items?

Tags: configuration, lxde

Where does the list of "Available Applications" come from? How
can items/categories be added/deleted?

On LXPanel - "Add/Remove Panel Items":

```
Panel Preferences
====================================
|Panel Applets|
---------------
|Currently loaded plugins|
--------------------------
[Application Launch Bar]     <Edit>



Application Launch Bar
==============================================================
|Applications|          <Add>         |Available Applications|
.                       <Remove>        .
.                       <Up>            .   
.                       <Down>          .
.                                       .
```

I am using lubuntu 11.10, LXPanel 0.5.8.

Answer (score 1):

Available applications are by default at `/usr/share/applications`.

New items can be added to `~/.local/share/applications`.

In order to edit an item, copy the corresponding *.desktop* file from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications` and edit it there.

To remove an application, also copy it, and then add the line `Hidden=true` to the bottom of the file.